# Count data from 7 months ago even if null

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with `datetime` column. I want to get data based on that column from 7 months ago even if there are no records for this month.

Table:

```
id | created_date
1  | 2022-11-08
2  | 2023-02-12
3  | 2023-03-09
4  | 2023-07-02
5  | 2023-07-07
6  | 2023-07-09
```

Query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(id),1) AS datacount, MONTH(created_date) AS datamonth
FROM data
WHERE created_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH)
GROUP BY MONTH(created_date)
ORDER BY MONTH(created_date)
```

Output:

```
datacount | datamonth
1         | 2
1         | 3
3         | 7
```

Desired output:

```
datacount | datamonth
0         | 0 or 1
1         | 2
1         | 3
0         | 0 or 4
..        | ..
3         | 7
```

Here is a fiddle to test it live:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ec4iyvQghDMe1dNivbERco/2

Comment: I don't quite get it. You also want the id's, where no records within the last 7 months is present to be in the list? But if they are in the list, shouldn't they be `datacount=0` and `datamonth=0`, as there are no records for them? Why could datamonth be `0 or 1` then?

Comment: your output is wrong in your question as december is part of the data that is selceted